# Disabling Apache Directives That Don't Have an "Off" Value

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, mod-ssl

I want certain Apache directives, like SSLCACertificateFile, to be enabled in some Locations, but disabled in others. For example,

```
# Require client certificates for http://example.com/secure
<Location "/secure">
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/my/file
    SSLVerifyClient requried
</Location>

# Allow access to http://example.com/secure/exception without certificates
<Location "/secure/exception">
    SSLCACertificateFiles none       # doesn't work
    SSLVerifyClient none             # works
</Location>
```

The documentation doesn't discuss any "off" values for the SSLCACertificateFile directive, though.

Comment: Just a typo? SSLCACertificateFile<s>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `SSLVerifyClient` turned off, `SSLCACertificateFile` is completely inactive, there's no reason to do anything further to 'disable' it.

In any case, you can't set `SSLCACertificateFile` separately in different `<Location>` blocks - per the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile), it's only valid in the main server config or the `<VirtualHost>` context.

Comment: SSLVerifyClient/SSLCACertificateFile was just a specific example of a general problem.

Comment: @IanDunn There's no general solution; the solution is different depending on what directive you're trying to disable in what context.

Answer (score 0):

To disable options that don't have an on/off option simply comment them out. Just be aware that some options are used in "sets", so you may need to comment out more than one.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I want to disable the options programatically at run-time, based on the Location. See the example in the question.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. As it stands there is no hint that this needs to be done programmatically, at run time or any other time.